# Qt placing widget on custom place

Tags: qt

I need to place(programmaticaly) my custom widget in specified place in my MainWindow.

On screenshoot I've marked red rectangle "widget" on place where I want to place my widget. I want place widget on top of QmenuBar and QToolBar.

I've tried setCentralWidget, but it expands widget on whole window.

Image presenting my problem

[image]

Code of my widget:

timers.cpp

```
#include "QtWidgets"
#include "timers.h"

static QLabel *createDragLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(text, parent);
    label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    label->setFrameShape(QFrame::Panel);
    label->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
    return label;
}

Timers::Timers(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QLabel *wordLabel = createDragLabel("dupppa", this);
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{

    initMenu();
    initButtons();

    TrackWindow *trackWindow = new TrackWindow();
    setCentralWidget(trackWindow);

    Timers *firstTimer = new Timers();
    //setCentralWidget(firstTimer); // suck

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to have free floating widgets overlapping your menu. In general you can only set the position within the bounds of the parent widget and set it via `QWidget::move(int x, int y)` in parent coordinates. So you cannot set the widget as the central widget, you need to set the parent as the `QWindow` that is also the parent of the menu and toolbar widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution: make `MainWidget` to be a parent of your *widget* but do not add it to parent layout. Then basically move your widget with `QWidget::move()` and and set its size with `QWidget::resize()`. This way you get a widget with absolute location.

An extract of working code:

```
#include <QLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow{ parent },
    ui{ new Ui::MainWindow }
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    menuBar  = new QMenuBar  { this };
    toolBar  = new QToolBar  { this };
    textEdit = new QTextEdit { this };

    menuBar->addMenu("File");
    menuBar->addMenu("Edit");
    menuBar->addMenu("About");

    toolBar->addAction("Copy");
    toolBar->addAction("Cut");
    toolBar->addAction("Insert");
    toolBar->addAction("Other tools");

    layout()->setMenuBar(menuBar);
    addToolBar(toolBar);

    textEdit->setText("Your widget");
    textEdit->resize(90, 30);
    textEdit->move(250, 10);
}
```

A screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That's great solution, but I tried to implement it to my program, and I can't make it work. I'm newbie in Qt and have to learn how to make my MainWindow parent for menu, toolbar, and other widgets. I'll still try until it will be done. Thank you for answer.

Comment: For any `QObject` you can specify another `QObject` as its parent. When you say `new QMenuBar{this}` you specify `this` as a parent of the newly created `QMenuBar`. In our case `this` refers to `MainWindow`. Now `MainWindow` is a parent of `QMenuBar` :)

Comment: I am not even remotely a Qt expert, but I basically wanted to show, that if you just create a widget, say `textEdit`, and set your `MainWindow` as its parent `QTextEdit { this }`,  then you can freely move it around just using `QWidget::move(int x, int y)` just as I did  `textEdit->move(250, 10)`;

Comment: Alternatively, you can set parent with `QWidget::setParent(QWidget * parent)` function. In my example it would be `textEdit = new QTextEdit(); textEdit->setParent(this);`